# Extracción de matrices de un dataset por columna con Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Me llamo Cova y soy totalmente novata en el mundo del Python. Estoy trabajando con datos procedentes de un escaneo hecho con láser terrestre, hecho en un bosque. Esos datos se organizan en un archivo .txt de 5 columnas donde las 4 primeras son las coordenadas de cada punto del escaneo y la última el identificador de cada árbol (hay 6).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder hacer los análisis que necesito con Python 3.6 he convertido los datos en una matriz que contiene todos los árboles (lista de listas), pero ahora necesito extraer de esa matriz grande, 6 matrices auxiliares con los datos de cada árbol. He intentado recorrer la matriz grande con bucle for para que cuando se cumpla la condición de que la 5ª fila de la matriz es igual al identificador del árbol, solo los datos de ese árbol concreto se copien en una matriz auxilar. Sin embargo me falta conocimiento sobre como hacerlo y solo soy capaz de generar matrices vacías. El código funciona hasta la condición del paso 3.

Script hasta el momento

```
#1.Cargar datos en una matriz (lista de listas) último elemento de la fila es elidentificador del árbol.

M = []
m=len(M)
n=5
archivo = open('0Arbolesavila7.txt')
for linea in archivo:
    M.append(linea.strip().split())
archivo.close()
print(M)

#2. Crear una matriz vacía para almacenar los puntos de cada árbol

matriz_aux = []

#3.Con un bucle FOR recorrer la matriz "grande". Si encuentro una fila con el identificador del árbol que me interesa, copiar fila a matriz nueva

for j in range(n):
    for i in range(m):
        print ("M[%d][%d] = %d" % (i, j, M[i][j]))
    if M[4]== 1:
        matriz_aux.append(m.strip().split())
    print(matriz_aux)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que no tengo acceso a tus datos, para este ejemplo generaré unos datos aleatorios, que se parezcan superficialmente a los tuyos:

```
import random
def random_row():
  return [22+random.random(), 73+random.random()/10,
          0.5+random.random()/10, 1067.5, 
          random.randrange(1,7)]

M = [ random_row() for i in range(20)]
```

M tiene esta pinta:

```
[[22.68126613889345, 73.0057696007351, 0.5565843334553301, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.15548802467382, 73.03800283269302, 0.5859144624897701, 1067.5, 4],
 [22.636175216416838, 73.03074273340518, 0.5812322674529596, 1067.5, 4],
 [22.75910540547213, 73.05377062031245, 0.5669467653723504, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.941376511789063, 73.08149558217094, 0.5059731459528295, 1067.5, 3],
 [22.61298878857939, 73.07970096992766, 0.5020074822402955, 1067.5, 3],
 [22.24859842841925, 73.02286016921904, 0.5140236040045504, 1067.5, 5],
 [22.193585603392542, 73.00484979334807, 0.5320641268108752, 1067.5, 2],
 [22.224968874493833, 73.07667990616066, 0.5757574110288602, 1067.5, 3],
 [22.76610517862379, 73.05820454432413, 0.5341395222433802, 1067.5, 4],
 [22.555035159495223, 73.06135380948234, 0.5613531314946592, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.755221456347908, 73.08201727774562, 0.5799244561183791, 1067.5, 3],
 [22.642936441611837, 73.0888657256796, 0.5949810318596735, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.627783144335986, 73.01858744552764, 0.5181457282824524, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.59716595441671, 73.05763920448436, 0.5633147404466163, 1067.5, 2],
 [22.390928912376264, 73.03575820302872, 0.5993740645154576, 1067.5, 6],
 [22.698658312517704, 73.05329864176538, 0.5158616073268263, 1067.5, 4],
 [22.97945392442473, 73.0262503418333, 0.5918265444469861, 1067.5, 6],
 [22.167365138455388, 73.03890842820707, 0.5900660404258454, 1067.5, 3],
 [22.928726892057895, 73.08067811529556, 0.5149996550372056, 1067.5, 6]]
```

Ahora quieres extraer sólo las "filas" que tengan un cierto "árbol" en la posición 5 de la fila. Es fácil crear una función que haga esto, y que retorne como resultado una lista con las filas encontradas:

```
def separar_arbol(M, arbol):
  aux = []
  for fila in M:
    if fila[4]==arbol:
      aux.append(fila)
  return aux
```

Esta función recibe como parámetros la matriz total `M` y el número del árbol en que estamos interesados. Crea una lista auxiliar (inicialmente vacía) que contendrá el resultado a retornar. Se trata simplemente de iterar sobre las filas de `M` y añadir a la auxiliar las filas que tengan el arbol en cuestión en `fila[4]`.

Fíjate en la forma en que escribí el bucle. No uso índices como `i`, `j` para acceder después a `M[i][j]`, como es lo habitual en otros lenguajes como C. Python te permite iterar directamente sobre los contenidos de una lista, sin tener que referirte a ellos mediante subíndices. De este modo queda mucho más legible y compacto, en mi opinión.

Obtener los datos del árbol 1 es tan simple como:

```
datos_arbol_1 = separar_arbol(M, 1)
```

Este sería el resultado:

```
[[22.68126613889345, 73.0057696007351, 0.5565843334553301, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.75910540547213, 73.05377062031245, 0.5669467653723504, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.555035159495223, 73.06135380948234, 0.5613531314946592, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.642936441611837, 73.0888657256796, 0.5949810318596735, 1067.5, 1],
 [22.627783144335986, 73.01858744552764, 0.5181457282824524, 1067.5, 1]]
```

### Actualización

Puede simplificarse mucho más si se hace uso de una potente sintaxis que tiene Python, llamada *list comprehensions*. Es más fácil ver un ejemplo que tratar de explicarlo:

```
datos_arbol_1 = [ fila for fila in M if fila[4]==1 ]
```

En este caso no necesitamos de la función `separar_arbol()`, ni de listas auxiliares. Esa única línea iterará sobre los elementos de M, quedándose sólo con los que cumplan el `if` y construyendo como resultado una lista que es la que finalmente ira a `datos_arbol_1`.

No obstante, para procesamiento y representación de datos organizados en tablas, como es tu caso, la práctica común y extendida es usar la biblioteca [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Aunque al principio puede que te cueste comprender su uso y sintaxis, si prevés que vas a tener que tratar a menudo con este tipo de problemas, definitivamente te compensará a la larga aprenderla. Si estás interesada, puedo poner una respuesta que use `pandas` para este procesamiento (pero sería más fácil si pudieras poner un enlace al fichero de datos, o al menos pegar como texto en la pregunta parte de ese fichero).

## Actualización 2: pandas

La biblioteca pandas está especialmente diseñada para trabajar con "dataframes", que pueden entenderse como una especie de tablas excel. De hecho puede leer directamente ficheros excel, csv, y otros muchos formatos. Una vez lo has leído, tienes la posibilidad de hacer casi cualquier cosa con los datos, como extraer ciertas columnas, las filas que cumplan cierta condición, hallar promedios, recuentos, desviaciones típicas, etc.

Para comprender y sacar partido de esta enorme biblioteca, tendrás que leerte la documentación o alguno de los muchos libros existentes. Pero sólo para abrir el apetito, aquí tienes algunos ejemplos:

#### Leer los datos

Supongamos que están en el archivo `"OArbolesvila4.txt"`. Ya que no sé exactamente qué significan las cuatro primeras columnas las llamaré "x", "y", "z", y "k". A la quinta la llamaré "arbol". Leer el archivo es tan simple como:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_table("OArbolesvila4.txt", header=None,
                       names=["x", "y", "z", "k", "arbol"])
```

Una vez leido podemos, por ejemplo, contar cuántas filas tiene, ya que en este caso `df` se comporta como si fuera una lista:

```
>>> len(df)
608
```

#### Filtrar datos

Pero no es una lista normal, tiene "superpoderes" ya que admite expresiones booleanas entre los corchetes, para cosas como extraer sólo los datos correspondientes al arbol 1:

```
>>> arbol1 = df[df.arbol == 1]
>>> # y ver cuántos son estos datos
>>> len(arbol1)
200
```

#### Procesar datos

También dentro de los corchetes puedes poner una lista con nombres de columnas, y entonces extraerá sólo las columnas en cuestión, sobre las cuales puedes hacer operaciones estadísticas, gráficas, etc. Hallar, por ejemplo, el promedio de las columnas "x" e "y" para los datos extraidos del árbol 1:

```
>>> arbol1[["x", "y"]].mean()
x    22.89170
y    73.12552
dtype: float64
```

#### Y mucho más

Tiene muchos métodos más, que permiten cosas como por ejemplo agrupar los datos según el número del árbol para después aplicar una función "recuento" que permita saber cuántos datos hay en cada grupo, tomando por ejemplo la columna k (contará cuántos datos hay en esta columna para cada árbol):

```
>>> df.groupby("arbol").count().k
arbol
1    200
2     61
3     66
4    281
Name: k, dtype: int64
```

O cuál es el promedio de cada una de las columnas x, y, z, k agrupadas por el número de árbol:

```
>>> df.groupby("arbol").mean()
               x          y         z            k
arbol                                             
1      22.891700  73.125520  0.552290  1067.533500
2      35.744426  73.292279  0.549164  1068.511475
3      19.364394  71.962955  0.571121  1067.271212
4      33.428256  76.393915  0.559299  1068.344484
```

Observa cómo todo esto puede hacerse en un intérprete interactivo (te recomiendo IPython o Jupyter notebook), y cómo pandas es capaz de imprimir los resultados en forma organizada y tabulada.

#### Gráficas!

Para cerrar, hagamos un gráfico de las columnas x, y, lo que asumo que serán las coordenadas de los árboles, y así veremos cuatro clusters, uno por árbol:

```
>>> df.plot(x="x", y="y", kind="scatter")
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Estoy intentando digerir lo que me comentáis. Estaría genial si me pudieras poner la respuesta con Pandas, porque sí que voy a tener que hacer cosas como esta en el futuro y prefiero hacerlo de la manera más sencilla desde el principio. No sé cómo adjuntar aquí mi archivo, pero lo he subido a Dropbox para que puedas verlo, es una versión acortada con solo 4 árboles para que el procesado sea más rápido. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhu35igc5sn9oy1/0Arbolesavila4.txt?dl=0

Comment: Ahí va, pensé que ya lo había puesto perdona. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhu35igc5sn9oy1/0Arbolesavila4.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Covadonga Respuesta actualizada

Comment: Tal vez quieras dividir tu respuesta. En mi opinión, pandas es la mejor solución, y tu descripción de lo que se puede hacer con pandas es bastante útil (mucho más completa de lo que yo añadí). Sin embargo, como tu respuesta comienza antes, la parte de pandas queda "sepultada"

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez quieras utilizar liberías para manipulación de datos com pandas.

Para leer un archivo separado por espacios:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+',header=None)
```

Esto te va a crear un dataframe que puedes manipular, graficar usando matplotlib, etc.

Es posible que quieras ponerle nombre a tus columnas para identificarlas mejor

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+',names = ["grosor", "edad", "otro", "numero_de_arbol"])
```

Y despues puedes filtrar tus datos:

```
arbol1 = df.query('numero_de_arbol == 1')
```

Un dataframe no es exactamente una matriz, pero creo te puede ser incluso de mayor utilidad.